# Problems with DatePicker in android

Tags: android

`deadline1 = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.deadline);
        int day = deadline1.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = deadline1.getMonth();
        int year = deadline1.getYear();
        final String date = String.valueOf(day)+"-"+String.valueOf(month+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(year);`

I used the above code for Datepicker but it shows current date not the one I picked using Datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the on date set listener for datepicker
See this tutorial to get an idea - 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/